# Redirect .htaccess to ssl https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I'm trying to redirect both www.site.com and site.com to https://site.com

My code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Somehow it's not working properly. How to make it work, and redirect ho https not only from homepages as I wrote above, but from site.com/page and www.site.com/page too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what we were using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirects anything with www out the front to the secure equivalent.

Edit: Updated to include the optional www

Comment: what about other pages? site.com/random for example is not redirecting to https version

Comment: Updated my answer to accept www and non-www versions. Initially misread the question.

Comment: Also, you should make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: I'm getting this error in browser: "This webpage has a redirect loop" for these .htaccess rewrite commands. I'm running Apache/2.2.26 (Unix).

Comment: Re: my comment. This was using Chrome 34. Apparently there are cookies involved in the rewrites and it's causing some issues upstream in the browsers. Firefox 26 is also having the issue. BUT Safari 7 has no issue with the redirect and works fine. Am starting to think this is not the best approach.

Comment: I found an alternate command sequence which seems to be more stable. I posted it as an 'answer'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're not already in HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And you don't want to match against the host to be `site.com` **AND** `www.site.com`, since it can't be both at the same time.

Comment: got it, but how to make site.com/random page to redirect to https: //site.com/random, now it works only for main page site.com and www.site.com

Comment: @user1482261 it should work for any request, make sure to clear your browser's cache

Answer (score 0):

The following seems more stable in Chrome and Firefox. It doesn't cause the 'redirection loop' issues.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/YOURDOMAIN\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```